# \t comes out in SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql

I have a query with tons of inner join and left outer join. It runs perfectly and gives me the result I want in SQL Management Studio. But when I run the .cs file, the string value of that query includes "\t" in some places like in front of the words "INNER JOIN". I did check the spacing between key words and all syntax are correct. Does anybody know when these "\t" things come from?

Comment: Are you running the query as a stored procedure or an inline query in your cs file?

Comment: It's not store procedure just a normal query.

Comment: Check if you have copied it from somewhere -means anywhere, even from your own workstation- and pasted, those tab characters might have got introduced. Many applications, like word/outlook, treat these characters in different way and when you copy text from there, these characters are converted as per default character coding.

Comment: Yap, thanks to ypercube and kaps. It has been solved. Because I copied the whole chunk of query from SQL Management studio to .cs file. I deleted those line with "\t" and typed it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yap, thanks to ypercube and kaps. It has been solved. Because I copied the whole chunk of query from SQL Management studio to .cs file. I deleted those line with "\t" and typed it again.

Answer (score 3):

In the debugger in Visual Studio, tabs will be shown as `\t` - this doesn't mean that SQL Server will not understand the syntax, it is just how the debugger displays special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the query in your cs code again to ensure you have not used \t anywhere. I don't think it will be inserted automatically in any case.

It is a good practice to use stored procedures instead of inline queries, so you might want to try using a stored procedure instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find where the TAB characters ('\t') are coming from and they are causing problems you can replace them with spaces before executing the query:

```
var query = "SELCET * FROM MyTable";
query = query.Replace("\t", " ");
```